# What is meaning of the syntax %||%?

Tags: r, user-interface

I'm trying to create a dynamic UI, so i used this code

```
output$col <- renderUI({
    map(col_names(), ~ textInput(.x, NULL, value = isolate(input[[.x]])) %||% "")
  })
```

from :

https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#multiple-controls

My question is basically, what is meaning of the syntax %||% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page of sheds light into it:

```
?rlang::`%||%`

Description
This infix function makes it easy to replace NULLs with a default value.
It's inspired by the way that Ruby's or operation (||) works.

Usage
x %||% y

Arguments
x, y    
If x is NULL, will return y; otherwise returns x.
```

It is similar to a coalesce function. Basically, whenever the input is NULL, that means it is not (yet) available, an empty tring is assigned rather than `NULL`. This is desireable because this is rendered and displayed as an empty value should. NULL would be shown like an error massage

Answer (score 0):

The `%||%` comes from `rlang`. You can find it on the `?"op-null-default"` help page. From the documentation

> This infix function makes it easy to replace NULLs with a default value. It's inspired by the way that Ruby's or operation (||) works.

Basically it returns the second value if the first is NULL.